# Definition and a particular example of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

A sequence  of objects in a set $S$ is, by definition, a function $f$ from the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$ to $S$.

I wanted to see whether the following function makes sense to say that we have defined a sequence of prime numbers.

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, $f(n)$ is $n$-th prime number. Here prime numbers are taken from $2$, and written in increasing order, and then enumerated as first, second, etc.

Does it make sense to say that this is a sequence of prime numbers? If yes, can we assert that $f(n)$ can not be expressed by any formula in $n$? (As we know there are infinitely many primes, but we do not an algebraic expression in $n$ which expresses the $n$-th prime number, am I right?)

Comment: You are right, this is a well-defined sequence, but indeed it has no closed form.

Comment: May I get to know what it closed form?

Comment: I mean that, as you said, you cannot express the $n-$th term in terms of $n$.

Comment: Can you precise what a *formula in $n$* is? Enumerating the primes is [primitive recursive](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Prime_Enumeration_Function_is_Primitive_Recursive#:~:text=Let%20the%20function%20p%3AN,Then%20p%20is%20primitive%20recursive.).

Comment: I mean, since currently exact values of primes are known up to a certain limit, but beyond it, we do not know the prime number; we know only that it exists. This is because, there is no expression in terms of $n$ and other known integers, real numbers, which give $n$-th prime number.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797362/is-list-of-prime-numbers-a-sequence

Comment: @TheSilverDoe What do you mean by *...you cannot **express** the $n$−th term in terms of $n$.*?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I mean that there is no "formula", in the (intuitive) sense that there is no elementary function (which can be expressed with usual operations and functions) who takes $n$ as an argument and gives the $n-$th prime number. I know this is not a rigourous definition of "formula", but I think this is what the OP wants to know.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I understand. But I think that it is dangerous to go in that direction. In particular, because understanding that a formula is a fuzzy concept is interesting in itself. In particular, a [closed form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) is probably what you mean by a formula. Right? Then [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) provides links between primitive recursion function (that $p(n)$ is) and closed form expressions.

Answer (score 1):

**Does it make sense to say that this is a sequence of prime numbers?**

Yes, such a sequence makes perfect sense.

**If yes, can we assert that $f(n)$ can not be expressed by any formula in $n$?**

This all depends on what you call a formula. For example you can find a primitive recursive function that enumerates the primes. See [this article](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Prime_Enumeration_Function_is_Primitive_Recursive#:%7E:text=Let%20the%20function%20p%3AN,Then%20p%20is%20primitive%20recursive.) for details.